# wikipedia pageview statistics and bots

Tags: statistics, wikipedia

I am currently analyzing the wikipedia pageview statistics from Domas Mituzas and I wonder whether the bot-edits on the wikipedia pages are included in the number of page views which are provided for each page.

Comment: Could you provide more background information? Or maybe a link to the statistics page?

Comment: http://stats.grok.se/ . This tool is using the data. I am just wondering whether changes by bots over the wikimedia API are counted as a page_view for wikipedia. Or does the API has direct access to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are, if you're talking about extremely old/stupid bots which do screenscraping in a particularly stupid way. The pageviews raw data just includes any request to a /wiki/ page, but not to /w/ like /w/index.php or /w/api.php. They are not real pageviews, as the reports clearly say: http://stats.wikimedia.org/EN/TablesPageViewsMonthlyCombined.htm

See also a more recent and more complete overview of the issues with page views data: https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Research:Page_view